# Moving files from one directory to other by skipping one directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to move all files from SrcFiles to TgtFiles but I should not copy the files from SrcFiles_Backup to TgtFiles using bash- shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
src_file_dir=/test/dev_env/proj/Data/ALB/ALBT/SrcFiles
tgt_file_dir=/test/dev_env/proj/Data/ALB/ALBT/TgtFiles
cd /test/dev_env/proj/Data/ALB/ALBT/SrcFiles/

for file in $(ls -1 Albt_Src_*.txt $src | grep -v "Old_Files"); do
    mv $src/$file $tgt/$file
done
```

I tried the above script. It is working when there is Albt_Src_ files in the SrcFiles. It is failing when there are no files names - Albt_Src_

However, the script should not fail when there are no files named Albt_Src_ in SrcFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to loop over all of the files in SrcFiles and then use `grep -v` to ignore the SrcFiles_Backup sub folder and only move the other files.

For example,

```
src_file_dir=/test/dev_env/proj/Data/ALB/ALBT/SrcFiles
tgt_file_dir=/test/dev_env/proj/Data/ALB/ALBT/TgtFiles

for file in $(ls $src_file_dir | grep -v "SrcFiles_Backup"); do
    mv $src_file_dir/$file $tgt_file_dir/$file
done
```

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all recommendations made there.

Comment: I tried the above script. It is working when there are files named - Albt_Src_  in the SrcFiles. It is failing when there are no files names - Albt_Src_

Comment: Please read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)